# Is it possible to mark a cucumber test as pending in real time?

Tags: cucumber

We've got a lot of test cases that require specific data to be in the environment but the environment is not properly populated a lot of times.

Right now we're failing those tests but I was thinking about running them and marking them as 'pending' instead if the data is not there, so then it's easy to just run those in isolation.

Is this somehow possible? How could I stop the execution of the cucumber test so that it's reported as pending (or any other status different to 'failed' or 'passed' could do if that exists).

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "real time", but in general yes. Create a new [custom output formatter](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Custom-Formatters) that creates a list of the pending tests and rerun them. The rerun output formatter, which is available by default, almost already does what you want. See e.g. [here](http://blog.crowdint.com/2011/08/22/auto-retry-failed-cucumber-tests.html). It allows you to rerun tests that have failed.

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/blob/master/lib/cucumber/formatter/rerun.rb) of the rerun formatter it has the following:

```
def step_name(keyword, step_match, status, source_indent, background, file_colon_line)
        @rerun = true if [:failed, :pending, :undefined].index(status)
end
```

Simply create your own custom formatter that only marks tests with the :pending status to be rerun. You can always mark something pending in the test, see e.g. question [How do you mark a Cucumber Scenario as Pending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064078/how-do-you-mark-a-cucumber-scenario-as-pending)

Comment: Thanks Tatu, by 'real time' I meant that the tests are not marked as pending (for example, the last link is marking the scenario as pending) but in our case, the feature file calls the ruby code and the ruby code tries to run but the data is not there, so at this stage (after the scenario has been invoked) I was looking for a way to mark the test as :pending (or a similar approach) from the ruby code itself. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `pending` in a step definition to stop the execution of that scenario and mark it as pending.

Comment: but can you do something like that from the ruby code instead rather than from the step definition? ie, we run the test but sometimes it fails because there's not data, so we wanted to mark it as 'pending' after the test has been run (kind of overwriting the :failed status)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'from the ruby code instead rather than from the step definition'?  What ruby code?

Comment: We have:

*feature file => steps_definition.rb => ruby_implementation.rb

We wanted to stop the test and mark it as :pending from the 'ruby_implementation.rby' file.

If I put 'pending' in that file I just receive the error message:
"undefined local variable or method 'pending'" :S

Comment: That sounds like it should work - you may need to provide a bit more detail on how you've structured your test.  Does the 'ruby_implementation' file contain methods which you invoke directly from your step definition?

Comment: Correct Jon. Basically we're using the step_definition like a link between the feature file and the ruby_implementation (where is most of the logic), but commands like 'pending' don't work there (they work in the step_definition though).

I am thinking about the workaround of returning a 'pending' string to the steps_definition, although that might decrease the readability quite a lot, so if there's a cleaner solution that would be much better.

Comment: Understand your problem - I've certainly run into this before where the cucumber world isn't available when calling out to other methods.  I don't recall how I dealt with it but I'm sure it's possible without killing the readability!  I'll have to dig through some old code and get back to you...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19633/discussion-between-mickael-and-jon-m)