# Is there anyway we can create test suite of feature files in Specflow similar to TestNG?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, specflow, specrun

Trying to create a test suite , in which I do not want to include all the feature files. Is that possible? This is in the lines of TestNG.xml test suite. Does Specflow provide any such feature? Is there any documentation for tags in Default.srprofile, using which I can manipulate to include/exclude feature files I want to run?

Comment: Have you tried using the @ignore tag http://stackoverflow.com/a/2966701/7038423

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure filtering for Tags/Features/Scenarios in the Default.srProfile.
See the documentation here: http://www.specflow.org/plus/documentation/SpecFlowPlus-Runner-Profiles/#Filter

Comment: Thank you Andreas! Will definitely try this out!

Comment: Andreas, I tried using <Filter> tag, although it works fine for single tags example: <Filter>@smoke</Filter> , it does not work when <Filter>@smoke  &amp; @new</Filter> in Default.srnprofile. that is when I compile the solution in Visual Studio, the Test Explorer does not list any tests. Am I missing something?

Comment: These are filters, so with '@smoke & @new' you filter for scenarios with both tags. You want probably all scenarios with '@smoke' or '@new'. So set the filter to '@smoke|@new'

Comment: Yup it worked! You are a Lifesaver Andreas! Thanks again!

Comment: new link to filter doc: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow-runner/en/latest/Profile/Filter.html?highlight=filter

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/3155323/andreas-willich

```
@smoke 
scenario: B
.....

@new
Scenario: A

--filter "@smoke | @new"
```

The ordered way of running test is not happening. It runs based on alphabetical order of how scenarios are defined